# Conversion of MQL to PROMQL Queries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, promql, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

Is there any way to convert the MQL queries which are already present in the gcp dashboard to PROMQL so that i can use that in prometheus & grafana and i can run and configure the dashboard directly.

Any answer would be helpful.

converting MQL to PROMQL no documentation found

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,there is no such option.I have raised a request in Issue Tracker, you can track for the updates at the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261969152).

Comment: This is behind the authentication page.
Is this still open issue?